# OpenGLES10: Apply Projection & Camera View

Tags: android, opengl-es

I need a little help with this:
android developers, Tutorials: OpenGLES10.
[a link](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/opengl/opengl-es10.html)

It all works fine for the first Triangle, until I put in the code for Projection & Camera View. This should rezise OpenGLES Square view to match Phone's screen, so object stay in propotions.
As a Newbie watching, the code looks fine and i have cheked with referencefiles, that there's not missing a parameter or something like that. But now i'm lost..! Can't see what's wrong.
If Projection and Camera code are applied, there is no triangle, but the app. is runing and the View with backgroundcolor are shown.

Here is my code:

```
    package notme.helloopengles10;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.opengl.GLU;

public class HelloOpenGLES10Renderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

// Set the background frame color
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    gl.glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);

    // initialize the triangle vertex array
    initShapes();
    //enable use of vertex arrays
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
}

public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    // Redraw background color  
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

 /* // set GL_MODELVIEW transformation mode (If outline from here to after GLU.gluLookAt() - it works when also outlines further down i code!
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();  // reset Matrix to its default state

    // when using GL_MODELVIEW, you must set the view point
    GLU.gluLookAt(gl, 0, 0, -5, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);  */

    //Draw Triangel
    gl.glColor4f(0.63671875f, 0.76953125f, 0.22265625f, 0.0f);
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, triangleVB);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
}

// Redraw on orientation changes // adjust for screen size ratio
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    // Make adjustments  for screen ratio 
 /*(If outline from here to after gl.Frumstumf() - it works!
    float ratio = (float) width / height;
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);  // set matrix to projection mode
    gl.glLoadIdentity();                  // reset the matrix to its default state
    gl.glFrustumf(-ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 3, 7);        // apply the projection   */

}

/*
 * Draw a shape, a triangle. first add new member variable to contain
* the vertices of a triangle
*/
 private FloatBuffer triangleVB;

//Create a method, initShaoe(), which populate the members variable
 private void initShapes(){
     //create a array 
     float triangleCoords[] = {
             // X, Y, Z
             -0.5f, -0.25f, 0,
             0.5f, -0.25f, 0,
             0.0f, 0,559016994f, 0
     };
 // initialize vertex Buffer for triangle
     ByteBuffer vbb= ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
             //(# of coordinates values * 4 bytes per float)
             triangleCoords.length * 4 );
     vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()); // use device hardware's native byte order
     triangleVB = vbb.asFloatBuffer(); //create floating point buffer from the ByteBuffer
     triangleVB.put(triangleCoords);  // add coordinates to the FloatBuffer
     triangleVB.position(0);  // set the buffer to read the first coordinate
 }


} // end
```

I hope some one can tell me, where things go wrong?

DevTool: Eclipse.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, I hope you read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Comment: I am really disappointed with the quality of training materials offered on android developers page. A lot of code is missing and it is often not possible to simply follow the example...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code looks resonable (if you uncomment the parts that are commented out at the moment). Your matrix modification code is quite correct and all transformations are applied to the correct matrices.

But at the moment you are looking from the point (0,0,-5) to the point (0,0,0) and therefore along the +z axis. But since the default OpenGL view looks along the -z axis, you actually rotate the view 180 degrees around the y-axis. Whereas this is absolutely no problem, you now see the back-side of the triangle. So can it be, that you have back-face culling enabled and this back-side is just optimized away? Just try disabling back-face culling by calling `glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE)` or change the `-5` in the `gluLookAt` call to a `5`, so that you look along the -z axis.

You can also try to use `gluPerspective(45, ratio, 3, 7)` instead of the `glFrustum` call, but your arguments to `glFrustum` look quite reasonable. Of course, keep in mind that both calls create a perspective view, with farther objects getting smaller, like in reality. If you actually want a parallel/orthographic view (where size on screen is independent on depth) you should replace the `glFrustum` with a `glOrtho`, though the parameters can stay the same.

Comment: Hey Christian.
Thanks for the help.
I finally got it wright. You point me in right direction with the pihntlook. However changing -5 to 5 in Glu.LookAt(); did't help, no either changing glFrusstumf(); to glOrthof();. 
But it did make me wonder why glFrumstuf()-ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 3 7); had an negativ number!
I think is odd that the projection is set to -1, so i changed it and now triangle shows on screen.

Comment: @RAJensen But like I said, your matrix functions and their parameters are actually correct. What have you changed?

Comment: Only gl.glFrustumf(gl,-ratio, ratio, -1 , 3, 7); to
     gl.glFrustumf(gl,-ratio, ratio, 1 , 3, 7);

The negative

Comment: @RAJensen So you mean `glFrustumf(-ratio, ratio, 1, 1 , 3, 7)`? This shouldn't work. It should be `glFrustumf(-ratio, ratio, -1, 1 , 3, 7)`, like in your code sample. If this made it work, the error has to be somewhere else. Maybe you can check the return of `glGetError` at certain points in your code.

Comment: But it make it work!  :D
And yes you have right in that something still wrong, 'cos it only works on Emulator5554 but not when uploadet to a HTC Wildfire S.

It's not easy to learn something new, if theres an error in the tutorial code!   :D

Comment: I am having issue on blending on camera preview, can anyone help.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26828344/additive-blending-without-glclear

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with this tutorial and it got solved when I changed the order of multiplying in the **vertex shader code** in the **Triangle** class. So instead of having `uMVPMatrix * vPosition`, replace it with `vPosition * uMVPMatrix`. I guess the reason for this is because `vPosition` is a row vector.

Comment: Thank you. I had the same bug. In dev docs the order is wrong and there is even a note that the code won't work with the wrong order of multipliers.

Answer (score -1):

Your call to gluLookAt trashes your modelview matrix. You should call this function with the projection matrix active.

http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/gluLookAt.xml

This code shows the triangle for me:

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    // Redraw background color  
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    // when using GL_MODELVIEW, you must set the view point
    GLU.gluLookAt(gl, 0, 0, -5, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

 // set GL_MODELVIEW transformation mode (If outline from here to after GLU.gluLookAt() - it works when also outlines further down i code!
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();  // reset Matrix to its default state

    //Draw Triangel
    gl.glColor4f(0.63671875f, 0.76953125f, 0.22265625f, 0.0f);
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, triangleVB);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
}
```

Comment: Hey Sergey.
Yes it also works here, but the Matrix dosen't scale to device screen. So Matrix is still applies as the default square size, so the triangle's proportions are not correctet to the device screensize.
The result is the same as before entering the code for screen ratio correction.

Comment: Wrong answer and a common misunderstanding. The `gluLookAt` represents the camera/ **view** transformation and therefore belongs to the **modelview** matrix (usually as the first transformation after a `glLoadIdentity`). Your example doesn't actually set a projection transformation (and therefore uses an identity orthographic projection).